# Dúvida sobre Struct e Ponteiro para Struct

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, struct

Estou com dúvidas no meu código sobre structs e ponteiros para structs, as dúvidas são as seguintes:

**1)** Porque não preciso colocar (->) antes de velocidade, por exemplo ( p->atributos->velocidade) em printf("\tVelocidade: %d\n\n", p->atributos.velocidade) ?

**2)** Se 'p' é um vetor alocado dinamicamente, porque eu preciso colocar "&" em imprime_pokemon_nome(&p[indice_pokemon]) e imprime_pokemon_atak(&p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque]) ? Normalmente eu defino minhas funções com vetores, na função *int main*, sem o '&', como, func(vetor).

**3)** A função void imprime_pokemon_atak(Pokemon *p) está com problemas de struct, mas eu não faço ideia do que seja.

Desculpe-me pelo tamanho da pergunta, mas acredito que falta essas peças para preencher minhas lacunas em struct. Obrigado!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{

    int HP;
    int ataque;
    int defesa;
    int ataque_especial;
    int defesa_especial;
    int velocidade;

}Atributos;

typedef struct{

    char nome_ataque[20];
    int poder_base;
    float acuracia;
    char classe;

}Ataques;

typedef struct{

    char nome[50];
    char tipo_primario[20];
    char tipo_secundario[20];
    Atributos atributos;
    Ataques ataques[4];

}Pokemon;

void imprime_pokemon_nome(Pokemon *p);
void imprime_pokemon_atak(Pokemon *p);


int main(){

    int option, i = 0, indice_pokemon, indice_ataque;
    Pokemon *p = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &option);

    while(option != 0){

        switch(option){

            case 1:
                p = (Pokemon*)realloc(p, (i+1)*sizeof(Pokemon));
                scanf(" %s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d", p[i].nome, p[i].tipo_primario, p[i].tipo_secundario, &p[i].atributos.HP, &p[i].atributos.ataque, &p[i].atributos.defesa,&p[i].atributos.ataque_especial, &p[i].atributos.defesa_especial, &p[i].atributos.velocidade);
                i++;
                break;

            case 2:
                scanf("%d %d", &indice_pokemon, &indice_ataque);
                scanf(" %s %d %f %c", p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque].nome_ataque, &p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque].poder_base, &p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque].acuracia, &p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque].classe);
                break;

            case 3:
                scanf("%d", &indice_pokemon);
                imprime_pokemon_nome(&p[indice_pokemon]);
                break;

            case 4:
                scanf("%d %d", &indice_pokemon, &indice_ataque);
                imprime_pokemon_atak(&p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque]);
                break;
            }
            scanf("%d", &option);
    }

    return 0;
}

void imprime_pokemon_nome(Pokemon *p) {

    printf("Nome do Pokemon: %s\n", p->nome);
    printf("Tipo primario: %s\n", p->tipo_primario);
    printf("Tipo secundario: %s\n", p->tipo_secundario);
    printf("Status:\n");
    printf("\tHP: %d\n", p->atributos.HP);
    printf("\tAtaque: %d\n", p->atributos.ataque);
    printf("\tDefesa: %d\n", p->atributos.defesa);
    printf("\tAtaque Especial: %d\n", p->atributos.ataque_especial);
    printf("\tDefesa Especial: %d\n", p->atributos.defesa_especial);
    printf("\tVelocidade: %d\n\n", p->atributos.velocidade);

}

void imprime_pokemon_atak(Pokemon *p){

    printf("Nome do Ataque: %s\n", p->ataques->nome_ataque);
    printf("Poder base: %d\n", p->ataques->poder_base);
    printf("Acuracia: %f\n", p->ataques->acuracia);
    printf("Classe: %c\n\n", p->ataques->classe);
}
```

Comment: Ao chamar qualquer uma das funções de alocação de pilha (malloc, realloc, calloc) 1) verifique sempre (! = NULL) o valor retornado para garantir que a operação tenha sido bem sucedida.

Comment: Ao chamar qualquer uma das famílias de funções `scanf ()`, verifique sempre o valor retornado (não os valores dos parâmetros) para garantir que a operação tenha sido bem sucedida

Comment: Ao chamar `scanf ()` com um especificador "% s", inclua sempre um modificador que seja 1 menor que o comprimento do buffer de entrada para evitar o estouro do buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Porque não preciso colocar (->) antes de velocidade, por exemplo (
>   p->atributos->velocidade) em printf("\tVelocidade: %d\n\n",
>   p->atributos.velocidade) ?

`atributos` é uma estrutura e não um ponteiro logo tem de ser `.`

Para ser com `->` teria que ter sido definido como ponteiro, assim:

```
typedef struct{
    ...
    Atributos *atributos;
    ...
}Pokemon;
```

E desta maneira seria também necessário cada vez que se cria um `Pokemon` com `malloc` ou `realloc`, alocar também espaço para o campo `atributos` da mesma maneira.

> 2) Se 'p' é um vetor alocado dinamicamente, porque eu preciso colocar
>   "&" em imprime_pokemon_nome(&p[indice_pokemon]) e
>   imprime_pokemon_atak(&p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque]) ?
>   Normalmente eu defino minhas funções com vetores, na função int main,
>   sem o '&', como, func(vetor)

A função `imprime_pokemon_nome` recebe um ponteiro, como podemos ver na sua assinatura:

```
void imprime_pokemon_nome(Pokemon *p) {
```

E quando fazemos `p[indice_pokemon]` obtemos a estrutura `Pokemon` e não o ponteiro. Para ficarmos com o ponteiro, temos que obter o endereço através do operador `&`. Fazendo uma pequena analogia para inteiros é facil de ver que faz sentido. Imaginemos que temos:

```
int numeros[3] = {1,2,3};
```

Quando fazemos `numeros[2]` obtemos um inteiro e não o ponteiro. Para obtermos o ponteiro para esse elemento teriamos que fazer `&numeros[2]`

> 3) A função void imprime_pokemon_atak(Pokemon *p) está com problemas
>   de struct, mas eu não faço ideia do que seja.

Exato, a função está a espera de receber um ponteiro para `Pokemon`:

```
void imprime_pokemon_atak(Pokemon *p){
```

E está a ser passado um ponteiro para um `Ataques`:

```
&p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque]
```

Para corrigir a função para esse problema podemos alterar a função `imprime_pokemon_atak` para que receba o tipo correto:

```
void imprime_pokemon_atak(Ataques *a){ //recebe agora um Ataques*

    //como agora recebe o ponteiro para o ataque o acesso é mais simples
    printf("Nome do Ataque: %s\n", a->nome_ataque); 
    printf("Poder base: %d\n", a->poder_base);
    printf("Acuracia: %f\n", a->acuracia);
    printf("Classe: %c\n\n", a->classe);
}
```

Notas adicionais:

Antes de `while` tem a leitura da opção que depois se repete no fim do `while`:

```
scanf("%d", &option);

while(option != 0){

    ...
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
```

Melhor é transformar esta lógica em:

```
int option = 1, i = 0, indice_pokemon, indice_ataque; //agora começa com 1 para entrar no while
...
while(option != 0){
    printf("\nInsira a opção");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    ...
    //resto do código
}
```

Também aconselho a por `printf` de cada uma das opções para ser fácil perceber que valores se está a inserir

Answer (score 4):

Victor
Minha resposta será um pouco longa, mas gosto de explicar os detalhes, pois sem esta base conceitual você pode enfrentar novos problemas. Acredite leve um pouco mais de tempo lendo esta resposta longa e poupe mais tempo no futuro.

SUA DÚVIDA: 1) Porque não preciso colocar (->) antes de velocidade, por exemplo ( p->atributos->velocidade) em:
printf("\tVelocidade: %d\n\n", p->atributos.velocidade) ?

Para responder a esta pergunta precisamos relembrar alguns conceitos

## PONTEIROS

A Linguagem C possui muitas formas diferentes de fazer a mesma operação. Muito disso surgiu da necessidade de otimizar o código fonte e também dar mais velocidade na programação.

Quando se trabalha com variáveis ponteiro que, armazenam um único endereço de memória dentro dela ,são necessárias a utilização de alguns símbolos especiais.
A saber:

**&** - Significa: endereço de memória de

*(asterisco) - Significa desreferenciamento do ponteiro (explico isso mais a seguir)

Observe o seguinte trecho de código:

**int x**; 
declara e solicita espaço na memória para alocar uma variável do tipo int

**int *p**; 
declara uma variável ponteiro capaz de apontar para uma região de memória estruturada como inteiro(int)

**p = &x**;
a variável ponteiro recebe o endereço de memória da variável x

***p = 10**;

Neste trecho de código *p = 10 ocorrre o desreferenciamento do ponteiro: ou seja, o conteúdo da região de memória apontado pelo ponteiro recebe o valor 10.

O asterisco * é tipo dizer: “ponteiro vá lá no endereço de memória que você esta apontando e coloque o valor 10.

## VETORES E PONTEIROS

Quando se trabalha com vetores(arrays) na linguagem C o processo é o mesmo. A diferença é que vetores possuem compartimentos de memória separados por um índice e acessados via colchetes[ ]
Vamos a mais um código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> /*para acentuação*/
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    system("CLS"); //limpa tela no windows
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");//acenturar a saída
    int vetorA[10];
    int *p;
    p = &vetorA[0]; /* coloca o endereço do primeiro elemento do vetor em p*/
    printf("\nEndereço de memória do vetor %p usando p", p);
    printf("\nEndereço de memória do vetor %p usando vetorA", vetorA);
    printf("\nEndereço de memória do vetor %p usando &vetorA[0]", &vetorA[0]);

    *(p + 0) = 10;
    /*Desrefenciamento: ou seja, aloque o valor 10 na posição de  memória contida
    em p + deslocamento 0(zero) */
    *(p + 1) = 11;
    /*Desrefenciamento: ou seja, aloque o valor 11 na posição de  memória contida
    em p + deslocamento 1(um) */
    printf("\nVetor no indice 0 vetorA[0] = %d e vetor índice 1 vetorA[1] = %d", *(p + 0), *(p + 1));
    printf("\nEndereço de memória do vetorA[7] %p \no mesmo que (p+7): %p)", &vetorA[7], (p + 7));
    /* *(p+0) pode ser simplificado para p[0] também são sinônimos e o uso dos colchetes
    foi criado para facilitar a escrita e otimizar código
    logo *(p+i) é o memso que p[i]. Assim *(p+1) = p[1]*/
    printf("\nVetor no indice 0 vetorA[0] = %d e vetor índice 1 vetorA[1] = %d \n \
        usando notação simplificada p[i]", p[0], p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

ao executar código aparece:
[image: tela da execução do código acima]

### UMA OBSERVAÇÃO IMPORTANTE:

O endereço de memória de uma variável não importa seu tamanho em bytes será sempre o  endereço de seu primeiro byte. Lembre que um ponteiro guarda apenas um e apenas um endereço de memória.

Outra observação importante é que na linguagem C o nome de um vetor é o mesmo que o endereço de memória de seu primeiro elemento. Ou seja, vetorA é o mesmo que &vetorA[0];

E quando você envia um vetor para uma função ele sempre é enviado por referência pois o que é enviado é seu endereço de memória na posição [0].

Ex: **funcao_qualquer(vetorA)** esta chamada é o mesmo que:

**funcao_qualquer(&vetorA[0])**

Isso responde a sua segunda questão:
*2) Se 'p' é um vetor alocado dinamicamente, porque eu preciso colocar "&" em imprime_pokemon_nome(&p[indice_pokemon]) e imprime_pokemon_atak(&p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque]) ? Normalmente eu defino minhas funções com vetores, na função int main, sem o '&', como, func(vetor).*

Isso também explica por que ao usar scanf com uma string, que é um vetor de caracteres, não precisamos usar o símbolo &

**char frase[80]**
**scanf("%[^\n]s", frase)**

*obs: %[^\n]s indica que o delimitador de leitura seja quebra de linha e não mais o padrão que é o caractere espaço. Com isso evitamos o problema de entrar com uma frase e o scanf não ler a frase inteira parando no primeiro espaço. Com isso scanf lerá a frase até achar um enter (\n)*

scanf precisa receber o endereço de memória de uma variável para pode colocar o que foi digitado pelo usuário.

Então na maioria das vezes usamos apenas o nome do vetor para indicar que o endereço de sua primeira posição será colocada dentro de uma variável ponteiro .
Assim o código  **p = &vetorA[0]** é o mesmo que **p = vetorA** ( são equivalentes pois, como disse, o nome de um vetor na linguagem C é sinônimo de &vetor[0].

***(p+0) = 10;**
Desrefenciamento: ou seja, aloque o valor 10 na posição de  memória contida em p + o deslocamento (zero)

Desreferenciamento: ler o valor da posição de memória referenciada (“apontada”) pelo ponteiro.

***(p+1) = 11;**
Desreferenciameno: ou seja, aloque o valor 11 na posição de  memória contida em p + 1 deslocamento (um)

Dúvida: O que significa *(p+1)?

Para acessar o conteúdo de N elementos a frente usamos *(p+N)

Significa que quando o código for executado o endereço contigo em p mais o deslocamento do tamanho do tipo do ponteiro será deslocado.

Um ponteiro apontando para o  endereço de memória do primeiro byte de uma variável e sabendo o tipo da variável ele será capaz de percorrer esta variável.

Ex: se inteiro (int) possui 4 bytes em determinado sistema o ponteiro pode percorre um vetor de inteiros deslocando 4 em 4 bytes. E é assim que ocorre mesmo! Por isso importante declarar o tipo do ponteiro para que ela saiba como percorrer a região de memória que ele aponta. Mesmo ponteiros void precisam ser iniciados com algum literal(rvalue) para que se saiba qual tipo de dados que ele aponta.

## AGORA CHEGANDO NA RESPOSTA DA SUA PRIMEIRA DÚVIDA:

### STRUCTS  E PONTEIROS

Um struct é uma coleção de uma ou mais variáveis, possivelmente de tipos diferentes, que podem ser manipuladas em conjunto ou em separado
Para se referenciar um dos campos internos dentro de uma variável do tipo estrutura usa-se o operador . (ponto) 
da seguinte forma: 
**.campo**
ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> /*para acentuação*/
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int matricula;
    char nome[80];
    float notas[3];

}Aluno;
/* Acima declarei um modelo para uma estrutura(struct) e criei um alias(apelido) para este modelo
de nome Aluno. Desta forma ao solcitar a criação de uma variável do tipo desta estrutura
pode usar apenas: Aluno nome_da_variavel_struct; */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    system("CLS"); //limpa tela no windows
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");//acenturar a saída
    Aluno *ponteiro_struct;
    //acima indica que ponteiro_struct é uma variável que vai armazenar o endereço de memória
    //do primeiro byte da struct. Lembre-se que ponteiro só armazena um único endereço de memória
    //Como o ponteiro_struct é do tipo Aluno ele saberá percorrer esta struct

    ponteiro_struct = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    //a função malloc aloca bytes na memória e retorna o endereço do primeiro byte desta região 
    //alocada. Contudo ele informa que esta região não possui um tipo. Ela é void*. Assim é necessário
    //informar que tipo de dado você deseja que este região de memória recebem alocada seja estruturada
    //Usamos para isso a conversão explicita(cast) para indicar que queremos que a região de memória 
    //alocada por malloc seja estrutura da forma da struct Aluno. O ponteiro_struct agora
    //saberá percorrer e manipular esta região.

    printf("\nDigite a Matrícula: "); scanf("%d", &(*ponteiro_struct).matricula);
    /* lembre-se que para acessar campos de uma struct usamos a notação ponto.
    <variável>.<campo>. A variável neste caso é um ponteiro e para acessar a região de memória
    que ele aponta precisamos realiazar um desreferenciamento. Com isso fazermos (*ponteiro_struct)
    isso indica que queremos ir até a região apontada por ponteiro_struct. Uma vez lá
    usamos a notação ponto para acessar os campos da struct. (*ponteiro_struct).matricula */

    printf("\nMatricula Digitada: %d", ponteiro_struct->matricula);
    fflush(stdin); //limpa o buffer do teclado e evita ler o enter e pular o próximo scanf

                   //mais uma vez temos a possibilidade de usar um sinônimo em C
                   //(*ponteiro) pode ser substituido por ponteiro-> veja abaixo:

    printf("\nDigite a Matrícula: "); scanf("%d", &ponteiro_struct->matricula);

    /* Esta notação p-> é mais nítida e um pouco menos carregada que a notação (*p). Além de ser
    mais intuitiva. Pode-se acessar um membro de um tipo de dado estrutura de dado
    usando ponteiro de duas formas:
    Usando um desreferenciador entre parênteses e um ponto (.) para indicar o membro.
    Usando o próprio ponteiro e uma seta (->) para indicar o membro.*/

    printf("\nMatricula Digitada: %d", ponteiro_struct->matricula);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nDigite nome do aluno: "); scanf("%[^\n]s", ponteiro_struct->nome);
    //string não precisa de & pois nome é o mesmo que &nome[0]
    printf("\nNome digitado: %s", ponteiro_struct->nome);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite a nota %d do aluno: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &ponteiro_struct->notas[i]);
        // seria o mesmo que scanf("%d", (*ponteiro_struct).notas[j]);
        printf("\n----Nota %d do aluno = %.2f: ", i + 1, ponteiro_struct->notas[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

## VETORES DE STRUCTS  E PONTEIROS

Agora vamos usar o mesmo código acima só que agora com um vetor de struct e structs aninhadas como parecido em seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> /*para acentuação*/
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int matricula;
    char nome[80];
    float notas[3];

}Aluno;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j;
    system("CLS");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    Aluno *ponteiro_struct;

    ponteiro_struct = (Aluno*)malloc(3 * sizeof(Aluno));
    //Agora serão alocados o espaço de 3 structs do tipo Aluno e o o endereço do primeiro
    //byte desta região será colocada em ponteiro_struct

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite a Matrícula: "); scanf("%d", &(*(ponteiro_struct + i)).matricula);

        printf("\nMatricula Digitada: %d", ponteiro_struct[i].matricula);
        fflush(stdin); //limpa o buffer do teclado e evita ler o enter e pular o próximo scanf

                       //mais uma vez temos a possibilidade de usar um sinônimo em C
                       //&(*(ponteiro_struct +i)).matricula) pode ser substituido por ponteiro[i] &ponteiro_struct[i].matricula veja abaixo:

        printf("\nDigite a Matrícula: "); scanf("%d", &ponteiro_struct[i].matricula);

        /* Esta notação p-> é mais nítida e um pouco menos carregada que a notação (*p). Além de ser
        mais intuitiva. Pode-se acessar um membro de um tipo de dado estrutura de dado
        usando ponteiro de duas formas:
        Usando um desreferenciador entre parênteses e um ponto (.) para indicar o membro.
        Usando o próprio ponteiro e uma seta (->) para indicar o membro.*/

        printf("\nMatricula Digitada: %d", ponteiro_struct[i].matricula);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite nome do aluno: "); scanf("%[^\n]s", ponteiro_struct[i].nome);
        //string não precisa de & pois nome é o mesmo que &nome[0]
        printf("\nNome digitado: %s", ponteiro_struct[i].nome);

        for (i = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("\nDigite a nota %d do aluno %d: ", j + 1, i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &ponteiro_struct[i].notas[j]);
            // seria o mesmo que scanf("%d", (*ponteiro_struct).notas[j]);
            printf("\n----Nota %d do aluno %d = %.2f: ", j + 1, i + 1, ponteiro_struct[i].notas[j]);

        } //fim for

    }//fim for      

    return 0;
}
```

A título de mostrar como usar duas vezes o simbolo da flecha -> veja agora 
a entrada de dados utilizando a struct aninhadas. Veja que me meu código para simplifica eu não uso alias(typedef).

Observe a função: **int Desenfileira(struct fila *fila)** 
que usa **fila->inicio->prox**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Declaração de tipos para a fila
struct no
{
    int valor;
    struct no *prox;
};

struct fila
{
    struct no *inicio, *fim;
    int tamanho;
};


// Funções basicas para a manipulação de filas

void IniciaFila(struct fila *fila)
{
    fila->inicio = NULL;
    fila->fim = NULL;
    fila->tamanho = 0;
    printf("Fila criada com sucesso");
}

int Vazia(struct fila *fila)
{
    return (fila->inicio == NULL);
}

void Enfileira(int x, struct fila *fila)
{
    struct no *aux;
    aux = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no));
    aux->valor = x;
    aux->prox = NULL;
    if (Vazia(fila)) {
        fila->inicio = aux;
        fila->fim = aux;
    }
    else {
        fila->fim->prox = aux;
        fila->fim = aux;
    }
    fila->tamanho++;
}

int Desenfileira(struct fila *fila)
{
    struct no *aux; int valor;
    if (Vazia(fila))
    {
        printf("Fila esta vazia\n");
        return 0;
    }
    aux = fila->inicio;
    valor = fila->inicio->valor;
    fila->inicio = fila->inicio->prox;
    free(aux);
    fila->tamanho--;
    return valor;
}

int Tamanho(struct fila *fila)
{
    return (fila->tamanho);
}

void mostrarFila(struct fila *fila)
{
    struct no *aux;
    aux = fila->inicio->prox;
    while (aux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i\n", aux->valor);
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}

// Programa Principal

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct fila *fila;
    int i, numero;


    fila = (struct fila *) malloc(sizeof(struct fila));
    IniciaFila(fila);

    /*Insere cada chave na lista */
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Leitura do valor (%d) :", i);
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        Enfileira(numero, fila);
        printf("Enfileirou: %d \n", numero);
    }
    printf("Tamanho da fila: %d\n", Tamanho(fila));

    /*Desenfieleira cada chave */
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        numero = Desenfileira(fila);
        printf("Desenfileirou: %d \n", numero);
    }
    printf("Tamanho da fila: %d\n", Tamanho(fila));

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Agora é com você. Utilize estes conhecimentos e tente ver o erro de seu código!

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia,

Acredito que essas suas duvidas existem pois você ainda não dominou ponteiros e struct.. vou tentar responder de forma simples e fácil conforme o que conheço.

> 1) Porque não preciso colocar (->) antes de velocidade, por exemplo (
>   p->atributos->velocidade) em printf("\tVelocidade: %d\n\n",
>   p->atributos.velocidade) ?

Perceba que P é um ponteiro que aponta para a struct, então para acessar o conteúdo do "alvo" desse ponteiro você utiliza o "->" e a struct, como é só uma coisa na memória você acessa com o "." , quando você pegar POO, entenderá melhor isso.

> 2) Se 'p' é um vetor alocado dinamicamente, porque eu preciso colocar
>   "&" em imprime_pokemon_nome(&p[indice_pokemon]) e
>   imprime_pokemon_atak(&p[indice_pokemon].ataques[indice_ataque]) ?
>   Normalmente eu defino minhas funções com vetores, na função int main,
>   sem o '&', como, func(vetor).

Esse indexador "&" significa conteúdo, como um vetor é uma array de ponteiros, você acessa o conteúdo dele para poder manipular.

e sobre a terceira pergunta, poderia postar qual o erro de compilação? obrigado.

Espero ter ajudado, eu não estou lhe dando a explicação mais técnica, mas a que pra mim é a mais fácil de entender.. Acredito que vc seja estudante, então aconselho a aproveitar o máximo de ponteiros com seu professor de estrutura de dados.